# How can I dynamically set css color in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am writing a list values from a json file to the DOM. I want to set each text object to be a different color. I found some resources for doing this, but I haven't been able to get anything to work.

my js:

```
.controller("Catalog", function($scope, $interval) {
 $scope.search = "";
 $scope.books = books;
 $scope.reverse = false;
 $scope.list = false;


 for(var i=0; i<10;i++){
  $scope.books[i] = {
  'color': ('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16))
 };
 }
 });
```

and html:

```
  <div class="container result">
  <div ng-class="col s12 m6" class="books" ng-repeat="book in books | filter:search | orderBy:'book.doc.name':reverse" > <a href="https://address/{{book.doc.name}}" target="_blank">
      <img ng-class="list ? 'col s1'" alt="Click to read {{book.doc.name}}" title="Click to read {{book.doc.name}}" class="img-thumbnail" /></a>
      <h2 ng-class="list ? 'col s12 m6' ">
      {{book.doc.name}}   
      {{book.doc.languages}}
      </h2> 
      <p ng-class="list ? 'col-md-10' : 'col-md-12'">
     {{book.doc.subjects}}{{book.doc.tags}}</p> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `books` variable that you are assigning to `$scope.books` is not set.

You can init like this:
`$scope.books = [];`
and than use it in `ng-repeat` like this:
`{{book.color}}` because you are only setting the `color` on the `for` loop.

If you have the `$scope.books` set than you can set the colors for all the books like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    books[i].color = ('#' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
}
```

Here is a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bardhlohaj/ngphaggu/8/).

Comment: I already have `$scope books = books;` Will that be a problem?

Comment: yes, you should change it to `$scope.books = [];`. Check on the JSFiddle.

Comment: $scope.books is defined, but the books variable is not

Comment: Yeah, it clearly works. Not sure whats wrong with mine, everytime I change `$scope.books` the text fails to display.

Comment: Can you tell us how are you changing it? Maybe show on JSFiddle?

Comment: Yeah of course. I just updated my question with more if the code so you can get a better idea of the context, as well.

Comment: you don't have any `doc` or `doc.name` etc. that you are trying to use. You should set these attributes on your `books` objects in order to use them just like `color` was added and than used.

Comment: I just quickly dropped what I had before changing it into this fiddle, I'll tweak it in a second though [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ngphaggu/3/)

Comment: And heres an example of what happens when I try to change the $scope: [fiddle that doesnt work](http://jsfiddle.net/ngphaggu/7/)

Comment: what do you really want to achieve on your fiddle? Change only the color of the books to random colors?

Comment: Yes. I want each book to display in a different color, and ideally each time it loads display a new color.

Comment: You have several errors on both of the fiddles you added here. I changed my answer to answer the issue that you want to solve with a smaller data set and removed the unnecessary html on which you have issues when setting the `ng-class`, issues with `ngSanitize` (`angular-sanitize.min.js`) etc. Try to learn the libraries and functionalities that you are trying to use as single ones because putting everything like that doesn't work. You can check the errors on the developer tools -> console.